# How can i hold a first letter of `h1` content after pressing backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i hold a first letter of `h1` content after pressing backspace. Here i used `keyup` function but its not allowing to write in `h1`. Can someone know how to do it?

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/5brr7sj1/3/

CODE:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var txt = $('.editor').text();
var splitTxt = txt.split('');

 $('.editor').keyup(function(){ 
 $(this).text(splitTxt[1]);
 });

});
```

```css
.editor {
  border:1px solid #d9d9d9;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  padding:0 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1 contenteditable="true" class="editor">
    Click here to edit content
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking like this https://jsfiddle.net/5brr7sj1/14/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var txt = $('.editor').text();
var splitTxt = txt.split('');

 $('.editor').keyup(function(){ 
 if($('.editor').text().length == 0){
    $(this).text(splitTxt[1]);
 }

 });

});
```

Comment: Kamesh, can you help me to remove the current first letter when i start to typing on `h1` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `keyCode`

```
$('.editor').keyup(function(event){

     if(event.keyCode == 8){
         $(this).text(splitTxt[1]);
     }

  });
```

Comment: Thank you! After holding the first letter, is that possible to remove this first letter when i start to typing on h1 tag?

Comment: Yes it is possible to remove this first letter. I suppose you want to remove when you type letter from A to Z ?

Comment: I have done a test [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5brr7sj1/15/). I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your function to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function split(text){
    var splitTxt = text.split('');
    var first_letter = splitTxt[1];
  }

  $('.editor').keyup(function(){ 
    split($(this).text());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the solution https://jsfiddle.net/5brr7sj1/6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var txt = $('.editor').text();
    var splitTxt = txt.split('');

    $('.editor').keyup(function(e){
       if(e.keyCode === 8){
           if( $(this).text().length === 1){
               $(this).text(splitTxt[1]);
           }
       }
    });

 });
```

If you need any change please add it in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Check this. I have checked content length based on that h1 values will be replaced

https://jsfiddle.net/5brr7sj1/10/

```
 $('.editor').keyup(function(){ 
  if($('.editor').html().length == 2){
  $(this).text(splitTxt[1]);
 }
 });
```